# paste quotation marks into character string, within a loop

Tags: r

Using R, I want to produce multiple character strings such as:

```
"modelCheck("var1_d.bug")"  
"modelCheck("var2_d.bug")"  
...  
"modelCheck("var10_d.bug")"
```

I would usually use a for loop and paste (if I did not have to worry about the double quotation marks) as such:

```
for(i in 1:10){
    str<-paste("modelCheck(var",i,"_d.bug)",sep="")
    print(str)
}
```

However, I need to include the double quotation marks within the character string, hence the appeal for help?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simply [escape the quotation marks](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants) with backslashes:

```
paste("modelCheck(var\"",i,"_d.bug\")",sep="")
```

An alternative is to use single quotes to enclose the string:

```
paste('modelCheck(var"',i,'_d.bug")',sep="")
```

Comment: This is giving me output that includes the double quotation, but also includes the slash: "modelCheck(\"var1_d.bug\")". How to escape the escape?

Comment: The backslash is not part of the string, it's simply printed that way. You can verify by counting the characters by hand and comparing with `length(result)`. More importantly, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Interesting. I am trying to create lots of openbugs script files to send different models (var1.bug, var2.bug, ...) to our computing cluster. I am using writeLines command in R to create these script files quickly. The escape seems to works properly for this purpose (having just tested it). I wonder why R shows the slash when using print though?

Comment: This seems pretty consistent of R, but I can see arguments both ways. There may be a way to suppress the backslash when displaying on screen, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: If you use cat() you should get un-escaped output. Come on gjable, aix answered your question ... give it the "check".

Comment: It also doesnt work for me with the escape. I have to evaluate the string afterworth, which makes this problematic.