# combining strings to one string in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine some stings to one. In the end this string should be generated: 
`//*[@id="coll276"]`
So my inner part of the string is an vector: `tag <- 'coll276'`
I already used the paste() method like this:

```
paste('//*[@id="',tag,'"]', sep = "")
```

But my result looks like following: `//*[@id=\"coll276\"]`
I don't why R is putting some \ into my string, but how can I fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453020/paste-quotation-marks-into-character-string-within-a-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for an explanation. Try using `cat` instead of paste for output to the console if you want to see that your strings are being concatenated properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tldr: Don't worry about them, they're not really there. It's just something added by `print`

Those `\` are escape characters that tell R to ignore the special properties of the characters that follow them. Look at the output of your paste function:

```
paste('//*[@id="',tag,'"]', sep = "")
[1] "//*[@id=\"coll276\"]"
```

You'll see that the output, since it is a string, is enclosed in double quotes `""`. Normally, the double quotes inside your string would break the string up into two strings with bare code in the middle:
 `"//*[@id\" coll276 "]"`

To prevent this, R "escapes" the quotes in your string so they don't do this. This is just a visual effect. If you write your string to a file, you'll see that those escaping `\` aren't actually there:

```
write(paste('//*[@id="',tag,'"]', sep = ""), 'out.txt')
```

This is what is in the file:

```
//*[@id="coll276"]
```

You can use `cat` to print the exact value of the string to the console (Thanks @LukeC):

```
cat(paste('//*[@id="',tag,'"]', sep = ""))
//*[@id="coll276"]
```

Or use single quotes (if possible):

```
paste('//*[@id=\'',tag,'\']', sep = "")
[1] "//*[@id='coll276']"
```