# Create textstring with " in it for API POST command

Tags: r, string, api, text

I'm working with an API where I need to post a couple of parameters. One of them is a colornumber. Below is my example. The problem is that once I use the command `paste` it adds a \ to the string. And therefore the command doesn't seem to work with the API. Is there a way to create a string that just sais `{"argb" : -16777216 }` in R.

```
paste('{"argb" : -16777216 }')
```

```
POST(url, authenticate(user, pw), body=list(58,'false','2000', '{"argb" : -16777216 }', 2000.0), encode= "json")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other posts on SO indicate that the `\` is only there for clarification in the console output:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45363267/7547327

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453083/7547327

And should work as if they're not there,
but if it's not working, you can `cat()` the output to remove the backslashes:

````
``` r
paste('{"argb" : -16777216 }')
#> [1] "{\"argb\" : -16777216 }"

cat(paste('{"argb" : -16777216 }'))
#> {"argb" : -16777216 }
````

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>